# Vertically align div content, that substitutes tr element on mouseover (using jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm working on a html table where I show more information on a row using jQuery.

The following is an example of how I'm doing it:
http://jsfiddle.net/rMXAp/7/

The jQuery essentially fades the row in question, by setting the opacity to 0, and adds an overlay containing the following div:

```
<div id="divOverlay" style=""><p>This is the overlay div.</p><p id="info"></p></div>
```

The jQuery then sets the div text based on the "desc" attribute of the tr/row.

The problem I'm having lies in vertical alignment of the text shown (in a div) in place of the table row, when hovering over it.

Things I've tried.

- "vertical-align:middle;" for the tr element, as well as the div.
- "min-height: 10em;" for the div.
- "position: absolute; top: 50%;" for the div.

I cannot set the div's "display" property to anything other than none, or else it would display below the table (see jsfiddle).

I'm aware there are many questions on vertical alignment, but given I'm showing a div using jQuery, and setting the html dynamically, would they be used the same way? Or how?

I've got the feeling I've completely missed something here...

Comment: Do you want the text to hover over the exact area of the current div?

Comment: Yeah, the row it overlays, my aim is to have it vertically centered in that space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh.. verical aligning...
I think the best method is using the `table-cell` display.

The problem is that for `display:table-cell;` to work properly, the parent must have `display:table`;

So I'd suggest something like this:

HTML

```
<div id="divOverlay">
   <div class="content" style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">
   </div> <!-- the content div will hold the content -->
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
// inside onmouseover...
$divOverlay.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        display: 'table', //set parent's display to table
        ....
    }); 
    //set the html to the child content holder
    $divOverlay.find(".content").html($(this).closest('tr').attr('desc'));
```

check out this jFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/SpacePineapple/4T42H/

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't have any problem by keeping content of "desc" data into a span.

Have took a span having `line-height:normal and vertical-align:middle` and added the `line-height for div.`

Edited your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rMXAp/11/)

Please let me know if you want something else.

**EDIT**

If you don't want to change the content of "desc" then you can implement like [this too.](http://jsfiddle.net/rMXAp/12/)

```
$divOverlay.html("<span style='vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block;line-height:normal'>"+$(this).closest('tr').attr('desc')+"</span>");
```

Comment: Interesting! --will use sometime.